# Invoking functions in python. I am a beginner and trying to understand differences in invoking functions in python

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python and figuring out the way to invoke a function and method. I see this is done with different patterns and unable to understand the difference. Following are the different patterns I have noticed:

```
object.function()
function(object)
function object
```

Example (imagine a object list_name)

```
list_name.pop()
sum(list_name)
del list_name
```

What I am looking on how to differentiate and use the appropriate way to invoke a function and method.

This question may look silly for most of you, but will be helpful if I can get through this.
Thanks in advance!

Trying to understand how to invoke the functions and method in python.

Comment: Your `function object` is not a thing in that `del` is not a function.

Comment: In a nutshell: you read the description of each thing to know whether it’s a function that accepts arguments, or a method of an object, or a language keyword. Depending on what it is, you’ll know how to use it.

Comment: Just do some research; see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)

Comment: Note that the first two cases are actually two instances of the exact same syntax. `object.function()` is just `(object.function)()` or equivalently `f = object.function; f()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a silly question at all. It's just that it's a very, *very* large one. I'll do my best here, but I don't claim that this is exhaustive by any means. Python is a massive language, and fully describing it and everything it can represent would be the work of a PhD thesis, not a Stack Overflow topic. But here, I'll do my best to summarize.

```
sum(list_name)
list_name.pop()
del list_name
```

Very briefly, the first one is a regular function call. The second is a method call. And the third is not a function at all; `del` is a special keyword in Python that's baked into the language. You can define things like the first two, but you can't define another `del`-like keyword without modifying the language interpreter itself.

Let's start at the top. Suppose we make the call

```
sum(list_name)
```

Python is going to look in the current scope for a function with the name `sum`. The "current scope" is usually the scope of the current *module* plus any local variables, though it can include class scope if we're inside a `class` but not nested within any functions. The function we're looking for is probably defined with `def`, though it might also be a callable object like a `lambda`, so technically any variable is fair game.

In the case of `sum`, it's probably the built-in Python function (available by default) called `sum`. Note that, generally speaking, the function that gets invoked in this case does *not* depend on `list_name`. The function is determined by what's in scope, *not* the type of `list_name`.

And that's exactly where the second form comes in.

```
list_name.pop()
```

This is not a top-level function call. This is a method call. Python is still going to call a function (again, usually defined with `def`), but it's not going to look in the current scope. Instead, it's going to look on the class of `list_name`. If `list_name` is a list, it'll look for a `def` (or other value) with name `pop` inside of the class called `list`. If `list_name` were a string, it would look on the class `str`. If `list_name`'s type isn't known until runtime, then it'll determine where to look at runtime. That's called dynamic dispatch, and it's a cornerstone of *object-oriented programming*.

```
del list_name
```

`del`, as I mentioned, is a language keyword. It can sometimes invoke methods (again), but in this particular example it won't. In this case, we literally just delete the variable called `list_name`, which is a Python-level operation that doesn't invoke any helper functions under our control.

Now, that's the basic, introductory-level explanation. There's a *ton* of Python magic going on behind the scenes to make all these cogs fit together and work the way we've come to expect. You don't need to understand all of these internal mechanisms in order to use Python effectively. Technically, everything is invoking functions under the hood. `list_name.pop()` is really turning into something like `list.pop.__get__(list_name, list)()`, which is how the left-hand side `list_name` turns into an argument. And like I said, `del` can sometimes invoke methods as well. So while `del list_name` doesn't call any functions we control, `del list_name[0]` calls `list_name.__delitem__(0)` and `del list_name.example` calls `list_name.__delattr__('example')`.

So the long answer is... it's complicated. At a surface level, when you see `sum(list_name)`, look for a `def` outside of a class (possibly one being imported from another module). When you see `list_name.pop()`, figure out what the type of `list_name` is and look for a `def` inside of *its* class. And don't regard `del list_name` as a function at all. That's something totally different and it's built into the language.